# Add Individual Product Clicked to Cart. React Context

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-context

I created a cart Array in my Context

```
 const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
```

I want to implement an addToCart `Button`, on Each Button Click, Add the clicked product to cart, and change the button from `Add to cart` to `Remove from cart` on that particular Product, not all products.

```
const addProduct = (product) => {
    setCart([
      ...cart,
      {
        id: product.id,
        drinkName: product.drinkName,
        price: product.price,
        url: product.url,
      },
    ]);
```

};

Shop Page

```
const { products, storeQuery, addProduct } = useProduct();
// Products are coming from Firebase

  const addToCart = (product) => {
    const newProduct = {
      id: product.id,
      drinkName: product.drinkName,
      price: product.price,
      url: product.url,
    };
    product = newProduct;
    console.log("cart Added");
    addProduct(newProduct);
    console.log(newProduct.id, "Clicked");
  };

<SimpleGrid
              columns={{ base: 2, md: 4 }}
              spacing={{ base: 3, md: 4 }}
            >
              {products?.map((docsSnapshot) => {
                const product = docsSnapshot.data();
                return (
                  <ProductList
                    key={docsSnapshot.id}
                    docsSnapshot={docsSnapshot}
                    product={product}
                    addProductToCart={(product) => addToCart(product)}
                  />
                );
              })}
            </SimpleGrid>
```

ProductList page

```
<Button
              isFullWidth
              onClick={() => addProductToCart(product, docsSnapshot?.id)}
              colorScheme="success"
              size={"xs"}
            >
              Add to cart
            </Button>
```

id: undefined, Why is that happening?

[image]

I also want to check if a single product in the cart is another component.

Something like this

```
const inCart = Boolean(
    Map through the cart and check if that product is already in the cart
  );
```

So that I can display an `incremental button` if it exists and display `addButton` if it doesn't.

Lastly, to access the quantity from any component.

To be able to display a particular product quantity in the productDetails page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't guarantee that each product document has an `id` field from Firestore.

Refactor code as :

```js
{products?.map((docsSnapshot) => {
                const doc = docsSnapshot.data();
                const product = {...doc,id:docsSnapshot.id}
                return (
                  <ProductList
                    key={docsSnapshot.id}
                    docsSnapshot={docsSnapshot}
                    product={product}
                    addProductToCart={(product) => addToCart(product)}
                  />
                );
              })}
```

To change `Add to cart` to `Remove to cart` label try.

```js
products?.map((docsSnapshot) => {
  const doc = docsSnapshot.data();
  const product = { ...doc, id: docsSnapshot.id };
  // Find product either added to cart.
  const inCart = Boolean(cart.find((el) => el.id === product.id));
  return (
    <ProductList
      key={docsSnapshot.id}
      docsSnapshot={docsSnapshot}
      product={product}
      addProductToCart={(product) => addToCart(product)}
      // Add extra props for to indicate if product added to cart
      isInCart={inCart}
    />
  );
});
```

Later inside Product page,
refactor as below:

```js
<Button
  isFullWidth
  onClick={() => addProductToCart(product, docsSnapshot?.id)}
  colorScheme="success"
  size={"xs"}
>
  {props.isInCart ? "Remove" : "Add"} to cart
</Button>;
```

Comment: Cool!... Now I'm getting the id, how do i change the button from add to cart to remove from cart

Comment: @AbdulAzeezOlanrewaju check solution updates

Comment: Thank you so much, one more thing, how do I calculate the total from the cart context

Comment: Check cart total computation solution on bottom

Answer (score 1):

Calculate cart total.

```js
const total = cart.map(product=>product.price* product?.quantity||1 ).reduce(previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue,
  0)

console.log({total})
```

Comment: Please help me check this, it does not work well. I thought it should be the quantity * the price

Comment: I get "050" when I have like 4 quantities on the product that has a price of $50

Comment: Check updated solution, you need to add `quantity` field on each product

Comment: 1 more please.... the isInCart prop from the ProductList, can I use it in another component

Like: 
const inCart = Boolean();

Because i want to use it in the ProductDetails page.

Please check the question again

Comment: items in the cart should be accessed globally via Context API or saved in Local Storage. then you can do that  `inCart` on any page including ProductDetails

Comment: It worked!... 1 more please, how can I access the quantity on the ProductDetails page.

Please check the Question again

Comment: cart items array should look like ` {
        id: product.id,
        drinkName: product.drinkName,
        price: product.price,
        url: product.url,
        quantity:2
      },`

Comment: Yes, sir... but i don't know how to display the quantity on the productDetails page, If i loop through cart items, i will have too much re-render. How will i do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242457/discussion-between-byiringiro-emmanuel-and-abdulazeez-olanrewaju).